# Angular Material Autocomplete and subscribing for new values

Tags: angular

```
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  constructor(private myService: MyService){}
  ngOnInit() {
   myService.getNewOptions().subscribe(options =>{ this.options = options})
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
}


<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I am following this example from the docs.  I am subscribing to a service that will listen for changes made to this options array.  When the new array of options come in from the service the drop down doesn't reflect the new/different options.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide your component HTML-template to make question complete?

Comment: sure, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

In your case options are updated asyncronously, so they do not update filtered options, - you should merge this changes in one `Observable` to control it like:

```js
export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements OnInit {
    
  readonly myControl = new FormControl();
  readonly filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  
  private readonly filterValue$: Subject<String> = new BehaviorSubject<String>('');
  private readonly options$: Subject<String[]> = new BehaviorSubject<String[]>([]);

  constructor(private myService: MyService){
      this.filteredOptions = merge(this.options$.pipe(map(() => this.filterValue$.value)), 
                                   this.myControl.valueChanges)
                                .pipe(map(value => this._filter(value)));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(this.filterValue$);
      this.myService.getNewOptions().subscribe(this.options$);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
      return this.options$.value.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
  
}
```

This looks obviously bad - I advise you to refactor in-memory filtration into the API ove.